# How to get full record from two tables in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not able to get full records from two tables using JOIN in SQL Server.

I need full details from both tables where `ID=1`

I have tables `Blog` & `Category`.

`Blog` table:

```
ID  BlogTitle       CatID       Public
--------------------------------------
1   Title One       10          1
2   Title Two       0           1
3   Title Three     NULL        1
```

`Category` table:

```
CatID   CatName
--------------------
10      Category One
20      Category Two
```

Query

```
SELECT 
    ID, BlogTitle, c.CatID, CatName
FROM 
    Blog b 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Category C ON b.CatID = c.CatID
WHERE 
    Public = 1 AND ID = 1
```

From this query, I get the following result:

```
ID  BlogTitle       CatID       CatName 
----------------------------------------
1   Title One       NULL        NULL
```

While I am expecting following result

```
ID  BlogTitle       CatID       CatName 
----------------------------------------------
1   Title One       10          Category One
```

I tried few thing but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just to double check: are the data types of CatID in both tables the same? Are you sure, you are storing the same value for the desired records (10 in this case with no spaces and non-printable characters)? You don't need full join when you have a constant filter on the left table since it will reduce the result to only that value excluding all nulls.

Comment: Please paste the output of SELECT ID, BlogTitle, c.CatID, CatName
FROM Blog b FULL OUTER JOIN Category C
  ON b.CatID = c.CatID
WHERE Public = 1

Comment: @Pred, Yes both CatID are `Int` type in both tables. not sure why this is giving me so much headace.. I have cross checked record in both table records are there.

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? To have a record even when there is no post with the provided ID is present or to have the category when both records are available and NULLs when the category does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Move the conditions from `WHERE` to `ON` to get outer join result:

```
SELECT ID, BlogTitle, c.CatID, CatName
FROM Blog b
FULL OUTER JOIN Category C
    ON  b.CatID = c.CatID
    AND Public = 1 AND ID = 1
```

Comment: I need to get only one record where id = 1

Comment: Do you mean you want only 1 record in total, where id = 1. Or you want only records with id = 1?

Comment: I want to get records where id=1 in my case ID actually is primary key so there will always be one record.

Comment: I am not sure what was wrong in the query i removed the stored procedure & recreate then it was working fine. I ran the same query outside the Store procedure & it worked. Which made me delete the SP & recreate it. I remember in MS SQL SERVER 7 version in in 1999-2000.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT Blog.ID, Blog.BlogTitle, Blog.CatID, Category.CatName
FROM Blog
INNER JOIN Category
ON Blog.CatID = Category.CatID
WHERE
Blog.ID = 1
AND
Blog.Public = 1
```

Comment: This wont get anything

Comment: @Learning  - This wont get anything from where? are you sure your data in tables and sample data in your question, are same?

Comment: Boy(@Learning), if you are not getting anything from inner join query then there is no matching records which can be joined in your table. Check if you get the records from select * from Blog where CatID=10 ; select * from Category where CatID=10

Comment: @Learning this means that your data is not what you think.

Answer (score 0):

You have `ID = 1` in your `where` statement and there is only one record matching this condition. This is the reason you are not getting all records.

try this instead of putting the conditions in `where` put it in `ON` clause. Like

`SELECT ID, BlogTitle, c.CatID, CatName FROM Blog b FULL OUTER JOIN Category C ON (b.CatID = c.CatID and Public = 1 AND ID = 1)`

Comment: I only need record with id=1

Comment: So why not a left join from post to category if you need only the record with ID=1?

Comment: Letf joing only bring srecord from left table & shows null for right table

Comment: You have a constant filter on the left table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use JOIN to get your result :

  CREATE TABLE #table ( ID INT ,   BlogTitle VARCHAR(100) , CatID INT ,   
   _Public  INT)
  CREATE TABLE #table1 ( CatID INT ,   CatName VARCHAR(100) )

   INSERT INTO #table1 ( CatID  ,   CatName )
   SELECT 10,'Category One' UNION ALL
   SELECT 20,'Category Two'

   INSERT INTO #table ( ID ,   BlogTitle  , CatID , _Public  )
   SELECT 1,'Title One',10,1 UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,'Title Two',0,1 UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,'Title Three',NULL,1

   SELECT ID,  BlogTitle ,  #table.CatID ,      CatName 
   FROM #table
   JOIN #table1 ON #table.CatID = #table1.CatID
   WHERE Id = 1
```

Comment: @Learning , Try above query.

Comment: This will get all records i only need record which meets the WHERE condition `where ID=1`

Comment: This will only get data from left table it show null for CategoryName & CatID

Comment: I tried query mentioned in question with JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN, INNER JOIN nothing seems to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138597/discussion-between-mansoor-and-learning).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.ID,B.BlogTitle,C.CatID, C.CatName FROM
(SELECT ID, BlogTitle,CatID FROM Blog  WHERE Public = 1 AND ID = 1) B
 FULL OUTER JOIN Category C
  ON b.CatID = c.CatID
```